# How to debug firefox extension after cfx run?

Tags: debugging, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to debug my firefox extension. I set

```
javascript.options.showInConsole = true
devtools.chrome.enabled: true
devtools.debugger.remote-enabled: true
```

run in sdk console cfx run, after that i go to `Web Developer -> Browser Toolbox` get incoming connection and i see my extension `main.js`. But after  that, the code in `main.js` already been executed. How to debug it after cfx run?

Comment: did you set dev environment completely? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Development_preferences

Comment: no, i set only this, but it should be enough.

Comment: Yeah, cfx run seems to set up a proper separate debug profile Firefox, but oddly enough it seems you can't even find your main.js in Browser Toolbox, in the get-started-guide examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bug 899054 - [Meta] Implement an Add-on Debugger](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=899054)

this is *really* close to landing (the UI bits in [bug 911098](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=911098) are in m-c), so if you grab a Nightly tomorrow, or the day after, it should be in there, and might just work (for some undefined value of "work").

Comment: That's cool! but, it's not the bug where you can't find the main.js of the example addon, from the script finder at the top right of the Browser Toolbox debugger tab.

Comment: If I understand correctly, will be able to debug the addon directly, without other browser scripts? And this is what i want)

Comment: i'm not sure i understand you, but what makes you sure this should exist? did that ever work?

Comment: I am not shure) According to the description of this bug hope so. Now i just use widget onClick to debug, as a temporary solution.

Comment: It does work for most scripts and addons, but not SDK-addon module js. (according to someone on IRC, that hasn't yet been implemented.)

Answer (score 2):

also, two other things might be messing with your approach:

1) when you use `cfx run`, that by default creates a new profile on every run, so any settings that you have changed will not persist. to avoid this, you need to specify a profile directory with --profiledir=DIR (warning: don't use your main profile).

2) if the addon main.js code has already run by the time you open the debugger, you should start firefox manually, setup the debugger, and then drag the addon xpi into a tab.